# Connect to / query rethinkdb from javascript without node.js

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I'm trying to create a simple in-browser web app to display the contents on a given rethink table with some nice formatting. I'm having trouble finding a way to actually connect to rethink without having to use node.js. All I want to do is get the data out and then run it through some styling/layout stuff. Node + dependencies are overkill for a tiny browser-only app.

Comment: If you're using a shared database, you're going to need some server-side language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're going to need a server. It might be node.js or it might be another language, but you'll need a server.

RethinkDB is not Firebase. It can't be queried from your browser. If you absolutely need browser side querying and can't have a server, you should use Firbase.

If you want to use RethinkDB, you can just have a very thin server that just redirects your queries to RethinkDB. This can be done over HTTP or over WebSockets.

**Why**

Ultimately, the reason why you don't want to query your database from the browser is security. RethinkDB has no users or read only accounts. That means that if your database is accessible from your browsers, anyone can come and delete all your databases (including your system tables) with a simple query.

For example:

```
r.db('rethinkdb').tableList().forEach(function (tableName) {
  return r.db('rethinkdb').tableDrop(tableName);
});
```

And now, all your database is gone :).

Keep in mind that this *is* something the RethinkDB team is aware of and working on.

https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/218

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I can live with that rationale. Even though this console I'm making is an internal-only thing for highly privileged users, it's still a huge risk.